# How does the modulus operator handle strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, modulus

I know how modulus works in general, but it is not clear to me how the operator handles strings.
Recently, I had to write a script which checks if a name (string) contains an even number of letters. This actually worked, using modulus 2 and checking if result was 1 or 0:

```
function isNameEven(firstName) {
    if (firstName % 2 === 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So I'm assuming the letters in the string were counted?

Comment: Classic Javascript.

Comment: Your example does not work its always false .... what you probably mean is the length of the string: ```if (firstName.length % 2 === 0)```

Comment: From the [standard](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#prod-MultiplicativeOperator): Left value is converted to a number, right value is converted to a number. If types are not the same, throw an error. If the operator is `%`, return T::remainder(lnum, rnum).

Comment: It doesn't modulus is intended for use with numbers (integers) not strings.

Comment: @SPlatten Yes, it does, since the operands are internally converted to numbers before the operation. Not-numeric strings are converted to NaN, which usually causes any math to result NaN, though NaN is type of number.

Comment: @Teemu, the parameter suggests that firstName will contain a name not a number so there is no valid conversion of a name to a number, hence the NaN.

Comment: Yes, I know that, but the fact is, that JS finishes the remainder operation, neverheless an operand being a string. The question was, "_how the operator handles strings_", and the standard gives the correct answer for that question. An empty string is a string, and `''%2` returns `0`, not `NaN`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is always `NaN`

```js
const oneLetter = "a";
const twoLetters = "ab";
const threeLetters = "abc";

console.log(oneLetter % 2);
console.log(twoLetters % 2);
console.log(threeLetters % 2);
```

Your function doesn't work if you pass it a string that can't be implicitly converted to a number that isn't `NaN`.

```js
function isNameEven(firstName) {
  if (firstName % 2 === 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

const oneLetter = "a";
const twoLetters = "ab";
const threeLetters = "abc";

console.log(isNameEven(oneLetter));
console.log(isNameEven(twoLetters));
console.log(isNameEven(threeLetters));
```

You could check the length property of the string though.

```js
function isNameEven(firstName) {
  if (firstName.length % 2 === 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

const oneLetter = "a";
const twoLetters = "ab";
const threeLetters = "abc";

console.log(isNameEven(oneLetter));
console.log(isNameEven(twoLetters));
console.log(isNameEven(threeLetters));
```

Comment: "Your function doesn't work if you pass it a string." ... it does when the string is like `"123"`